# Intersection of instance data and list

Tags: python

I have a list of instances of a class:

```
>>> class A:
...     
...     def __init__(self,l=None):
...         self.data=l

>>> k=list()
>>> for x in range(5):
...     k.append(A(x))
```

Now I need to intersect the 'data' field against a given list

```
>>> m=[0,2]
>>> f=set([r.data  for r in k]) & set(m)
>>> f
set([0, 2])
```

So far so good.
But now, I need to get the instances of 'A' which had 'data' having one the values in intersection set 'f'.

Is there an easier way to achieve all of this - rather than iterating through instances again?

Comment: So you need a `list` of `[k[0], k[2]]` ?

Comment: What should happen if two instances have the same data?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `f = map(A, m)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in k if x.data in f]
[<__main__.A instance at 0x92b1c0c>, <__main__.A instance at 0x92b1c4c>]
```

Answer (score 0):

While iterating, you can check if the item is in the `m` list.

```
class A:  
    def __init__(self,l=None):
        self.data=l
result=[]
k=list()
m=[0,2]
for x in range(5):
    some_A= A(x)
    k.append(someA)
    if x in m:
       result.append(someA)

print result
[<__main__.A instance at 0x021CBEB8>, <__main__.A instance at 0x021CBF08>]
```